# Trigger builds remotely (e.g., from scripts) syntax in Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am using this option in my freestyle jobs but now my team is moving to make a standard format so I have to write all my freestyle jobs in Pipeline script and I google a lot but didn't get how could I write this option in the Pipeline script.

Answer (score 6):

You can trigger remote Jenkins jobs using `triggerRemoteJob` pipeline step.

> Documentation: https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/Parameterized-Remote-Trigger/

And here is a short example that illustrates how to use this step with authentication. I used Jenkins User Token for authentication - the token and user name was stored in the Jenkins credentials with id `xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx` (obfuscated id ofc). The remote job in the below example is triggered with a single parameter `foo` == `qwe123`, and it is configured to wait until the remote job gets completed, and if it fails, the job that triggered the remote job fails as well.

```groovy
pipeline {
  agent any

  stages {
    stage("Execute remote job") {
      steps {
        script {
          def jobUrl = "https://remote-jenkins-host/job/remote-job-to-trigger/"

          withCredentials([[$class: 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding', credentialsId: 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx', usernameVariable: 'USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'TOKEN']]) {

            def handle = triggerRemoteJob job: jobUrl,
                  blockBuildUntilComplete: true,
                  shouldNotFailBuild: true,
                  parameters: "foo=qwe123",
                  auth: TokenAuth(apiToken: env.TOKEN, userName: env.USERNAME)

            echo "Remote tests status: ${handle.buildStatus.toString()}"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks,
But for this we need the plugin installed and I don't have any plugin or I don't even want that's why I am looking for another way.

Comment: Alternatively, you can try using `curl` and Jenkins REST API, but using `triggerRemoteJob` is much simpler, and offers features a single curl request won't support (e.g. handling remote job status etc.)

Comment: How do you set this build trigger in the Jenkinsfile for the downstream job itself to allow  the downstream job to be triggered by a specified token?