# configure jenkinsfile to allow remote trigger for the job

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-job-dsl

How can I configure my jenkinsfile to allow for remote triggers in the job.

The option is available if I try to configure a regular job, as shown in the image below, but I could not figure out a way for the same via jenkinsfile.
[image]

can someone help for the same.

Update:
Trigger option available under jenkins' "pipeline syntax" help.
[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trigger builds remotely (e.g., from scripts) syntax in Jenkinsfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59025583/trigger-builds-remotely-e-g-from-scripts-syntax-in-jenkinsfile)

Comment: @RC0993 No, the answer you pointed tells about how I can trigger a job(a remote enabled job) from another job. But for a job to be triggered remotely, the same needs to be enabled in the job itself. Refer to the image I shared in the question. Thanks.

Comment: `Jenkinsfile` defines a logic, executed when a job is executed. Most of the options you have to provision by using other mechanism, e.g. [Job DSL plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/job-dsl/). How the job which should be allowed to be triggered remotely is created?

Comment: The job was created using the dsl plugin as "jenkins pipeline" type job. but I just used the mentions the path of my jenkins file and everything(including all the parameters) are defined in the jenkinfile only. I prefer to keep the configuration in the code so that its manageable in case of accidental deletions. 
I'm looking forward for an option in jenkinsfile itself where I can define that the job can be trigerred remotely.

Comment: I just the question with trigger options which can be configured in the jenkinsfile.

Answer (score 1):

just add 'authenticationToken('token_name')' in the pipelineJob closure. It worked for me. See documentation:
https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#method/javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.jobs.WorkflowJob.authenticationToken

Comment: Hi @leputz. Is this still valid? Its failing for me.

Comment: yes. it is working now.

Comment: Could you please share your Jenkins pipeline script