# set pipelineTriggers in Jenkinsfile to set 'Trigger builds remotely (e.g., from scripts)'

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a Jenkinsfile and I want to set a pipelineTrigger property for my stage 'setup parameters'

```
#! /usr/bin/env groovy
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('setup parameters'){
            steps{
                script{
                    properties([
                        parameters([
                            string(name: 'payload', defaultValue: '')
                        ]),
                        pipelineTriggers(])

                    ])

                }
            }
        }
```

What i'm trying to do is after the first attempted run of the Job, the following checkbox should be checked with token filled out.

[image]

When I have looked for the pipeline syntax, it does not list this as one of the trigger options.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59025583/trigger-builds-remotely-e-g-from-scripts-syntax-in-jenkinsfile?

Answer (score 0):

It's `authenticationToken` in the pipelineJob:

```
pipelineJob('project-name') {
  definition {
    ...
  }
  parameters {
    ...
  }
  authenticationToken('TOKENHERE')
}
```

https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#method/javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.jobs.WorkflowJob.authenticationToken